# How to display div only if exist in other div

Tags: css, sass

I want to display **.tel** in **#header** only if it's exists in **#switcher**.
The basic situation:

```
<div id="switcher"><div class="tel"></div></div>
<div id="header"><div class="tel"></div></div>
```

But user in system can turn off displaying **.tel** in **#switcher**. After that the code is something like this:

```
<div id="switcher"></div>
<div id="header"><div class="tel"></div></div>
```

In that situation I want to hide **.tel** in **#header** .

I know how to do it with jquery, but can I do it just with css or scss ?

Comment: This isn't possible with your current structure in pure CSS. You cannot travel "up" a structure in CSS, so the content of `#swticher` cannot influence the content of `#header`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution depends on where `<div id=switcher>` needs to appear on the page, but... if you're crafty, you can re-order your markup something like this:

```
<header>

<div id="switcher">
<div class="tel"></div>
</div>

<div class="tel"></div>

</header>
```

and then use the following style rules:

```
header .tel {
display: none;
}

header #switcher .tel,
header #switcher ~ .tel {
display:block;
}
```